using ACPIPOWERBUTTON function in a virtual machine
I'm running Xubuntu 24.04.01 in a virtual machine.
From time to time I would like to shutdown the machine with the host command
VBoxManage controlvm $machine acpipowerbutton
That works on other machines (Home Assistant for example) without a problem.
Xubuntu stops and displays the graphical window with the options to reboot etc.
That stops the automatic shutdown of that system.
What to modify to disable the display of the option window and just shut down the system without asking?
Thx, man
